# I use .db file from assets, how do I create new table?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a newbie in android dev. I use .db file from assets. Can I create new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DB is in Assets you have to copy it in the local path at the start of the application. See code below:

```
try {
    String inputFilename = "database_name.db";
    InputStream input = getContext().getAssets().open(inputFilename);
    String outputFilename = getContext().getFilesDir().getPath()+inputFilename;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, you may open your DB:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(activity.getFilesDir().getPath()+"database_name.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
try {
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name ( ... )");
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Obviously you don't need particular permissions unless you want to move DB in external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sqlite Manager plugin for Firefox to open the Sqlite db. Creating and deleting tables can be done using sqlite manager.